# How to view Block Device files

Tags: hard-drive

I am looking for some help understanding what "block device" files are and how to edit them.

I am a certified field engineer for Xerox and I currently work for an Authorized Service Provider (ASP). Part of our operation includes refurbishing old/used machines to use as service loaners or resell them. Part of this process includes resetting the meters (print counts) and this is proving to be a challenge on the new Xerox C81xx line of copiers.

When I remove the internal hard drive from one of the C81xx's and plug it into a Windows PC the OS does not recognize the drive. However, when I attach the drive to a machine running Ubuntu I can see the drive and all the partitions in GParted. However, when I navigate to the /dev folder and try to open any of the sdc files I get:

> **Could Not Display "sdc"**
> There is no application installed for "block device" files.

Is it possible for me to open these files to at least view the contents? This is kind of a shot in the dark. All of my tricks to "break" the machine have failed up to this point. I appreciate any help/feedback!

Comment: The files on a hard drive (or block device) are usually stored in a partition. “sdc” is a block device, probably the third device connected to the system. “sdc1 ” would be the first partition on “sdc” so that is more likely where any files are likely to be. If you use the disks app you should be able to see any partitions on “sdc” and mount them. Then the file manager should be able to browse them. If this doesn’t work try the terminal command `lsblk -t -e 7`  that should list the partitions on the system together with the file systems in use